# Catan: Can I move my boat in the first round of the game?

Tags: catan-seafarers

If I build two boats during the setup, can I move one of them during the first round of the game? Or does the setup count as the first round which would mean that I can't move the boat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can move a ship in the first round of the game.

The setup step is something that happens before the first turn of the game begins; it doesn't happen "during a turn". There's no difference between the first turn and any later turn in terms of moving boats or anything else.